# how to change elasticserach query result type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I saved a type of datetime data to ES, in the search results, this field type was converted into a timestamp(integer), is there any way to turn into a string(just by modifying the query parameters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify fields in the query then elasticsearch returns the fields in the format that you originally stored it:

You have two options ,

1. You can specify the date format at index time and return the same.
2. You can use scripts to format the date in the format you need.

curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/myindex/test/_search?pretty -d '

```
{  
 "query":{  
   "match_all":{ }
 },
 "script_fields":{  
   "aDate":{  
      "script":"if (!_source.myDate?.equals('null')) new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss').format(new java.util.Date(_source.myDate));"
   }
 }
}'
```

I would choose the firat one as scripts are generally a lot more expensive.